# How to change the order of Magento backend menu

Tags: admin, backend, menu

How can I change the order of the Magento Admin-Menu (Backend)? 
Please take a look a the picture. For example I want to move `Kundenmeinungen und Bewertungen` between `Kategorien verwalten` and `Attribute`. Is that possible and how?

http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160311/8uc4k5iy.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its possible but you need to change Magento core file. To do so, perform below steps:

**Step 1:** Take backup of below file.

> MAGENTO_ROOT/app/code/core/Magento/Review/etc/adminhtml.xml

**Step 2:** Open `MAGENTO_ROOT/app/code/core/Magento/Review/etc/adminhtml.xml` file in your preferred editor and search `<sort_order>50</sort_order>` config tag.  This is the child node of `config > menu > catalog > children > review_ratings`. Once you find this string replace **`50`** with **`20`** to set its display order.

That's you get this menu beneath of `Manage Categories`

> **PS:** Please note that if you changed any core files, there might be
>   possibilities to lost that changes in future, if you upgrade your
>   Magento version or any Magento patch having same file which you
>   modified earlier.

Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: magento will not overwrite xml files from local codepool

Comment: @MineshPatel, thanks for remind me, I updated my answer.

Comment: Is this solution work for you?

Comment: yes it works! !

Comment: is there any way to do this WITHOUT changing core files? I have custom module and I need to change it's order in adminhtml menu

Answer (score 1):

You can override adminhtml.xml by simply copying the same structure to your own plugin. and then just change the sort_order. you only need to copy the relevant menu item along with its parent if it is a child item. For instance this to change dashboard sort order:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <dashboard translate="title" module="adminhtml">
            <title>Dashboard</title>
            <sort_order>110</sort_order>
            <action>adminhtml/dashboard</action>
        </dashboard>    
    </menu>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Go to your module's etc/adminhtml.xml or  etc/config.xml

search for menu tag and change or add sort_order attribute as your want for particular child

example : `<sort_order>15</sort_order>`

Comment: Could you explain in more detail , please?

Comment: You must have custom module for which you want to change menu order. for that go to your module's etc folder you will find adminhtml.xml  if adminhtml.xml  is not available open config.xml file in that you will find <menu> tag

Comment: can you tell me the whole path to these files? I cant found it in app/etc/modules/

Comment: app/code/community  OR  app/code/local  Namespace/Modulename/etc

Comment: @MineshPatel, I guess Christian wants to re-order `Reviews And Ratings` menu item rather than it own module.

Comment: @JayeshPatel Okay. language is different so i haven’t checked

Comment: solved. thank you